# RegEx Problem using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a little problem on RegEx pattern in c#. Here's the rule below:

input: 1234567
expected output: 123/1234567

Rules:

1. Get the first three digit in the input. //123
2. Add /
3. Append the the original input. //123/1234567
4. The expected output should looks like this: 123/1234567

here's my regex pattern:

```
regex rx = new regex(@"((\w{1,3})(\w{1,7}))");
```

but the output is incorrect. 123/4567

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is:

```
string s = Regex.Replace("1234567", @"^\w{3}", "$&/$&"););
```

That would capture `123` and replace it to `123/123`, leaving the tail of `4567`.

- `^\w{3}` - Matches the first 3 characters.
- `$&` - replace with the whole match.

You could also do `@"^(\w{3})"`, `"$1/$1"` if you are more comfortable with it; it is better known.

Comment: Note that this doesn't support spaces or odd characters. You can use `.{3}` for the first 3 characters or every kind.

Comment: Thanks kobi, I would also try that one.  - kurt

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear why you need a RegEx for this. Why not just do:

```
string x = "1234567";
string result = x.Substring(0, 3) + "/" + x;
```

Comment: Hi Eddie, Good day! I have a little problem on RegEx pattern in c#. Please take note it should be done using RegEx pattern only. I already resolved this using substring() but I need to convert it using RegEx because I'll put the RegEx pattern on my config file so that there will be no data manipulatin inside my code. I hope you get my point.

Thank you.

Comment: Almost +1, but it should be `x.Substring(0, 3) + "/" + x;`

Comment: Good catch Kobi. I fixed it in the original.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
string s = @"1234567";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\w{3})(\w+)", @"$1/$1$2");
```

Instead of trying to match part of the string, then match the whole string, just match the whole thing in two capture groups and reuse the first one.

Comment: Exactly Alan that's what i'm looking for. Thank you so much guys you help me alot. 

@sam,eddie : thank you guys..

Answer (score 2):

Use positive look-ahead assertions, as they don't 'consume' characters in the current input stream, while still capturing input into groups:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?'group1'?=\w{1,3})(?'group2'?=\w{1,7})");
```

group1 should be 123, group2 should be 1234567.

Comment: hi sam, thank you for the reply. But I use the Match function. Is this correct? here's my code: 

 Regex re = null;
 Match match = null;
 string input = "1234567";

re = new Regex(@"((\w{1,3})(\w{1,32}))");
match = re.Match(input);

How do i apply the code that you proposed? Thanks a lot sam.

Regards,
kurt

Comment: use match.Groups[groupName] to get named groups (ie match.Groups["group1"] == "123" )